# Por que no funcionan clausulas on delete cascade

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USUARIO( Email varchar(50),Password varchar(50),Nombre varchar(50),Apellidos varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(Email))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CRIPTOMONEDAS(ID VARCHAR(10),NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NULL,PRIMARY KEY(ID))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LCRIPTO(ID VARCHAR(10),EMAIL VARCHAR(50),PRIMARY KEY(ID,EMAIL),FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES CRIPTOMONEDAS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE)engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERFILES(EMAIL VARCHAR(50),NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),FOTOPERFIL VARCHAR(50), TIPOPERFIL VARCHAR(50),CANTIDAD NUMERIC(9) NULL,PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL,NOMPERFIL), FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PARES(ID VARCHAR(10), BASECURRENCY VARCHAR(10), QUOTECURRENCY VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(ID))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LPARES(ID VARCHAR(10), NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID, NOMPERFIL), FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PARES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(NOMPERFIL) REFERENCES PERFILES(NOMPERFIL) ON DELETE CASCADE);
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRANSACCIONES(EMAIL VARCHAR(50),NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),NOMBREPAR VARCHAR(10),TIPOCOMPRA VARCHAR(15),FECHA DATETIME,CANTIDAD DOUBLE,PRECIO DOUBLE,PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL,NOMPERFIL,FECHA),FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO (EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE ,FOREIGN KEY (NOMPERFIL) REFERENCES PERFILES(NOMPERFIL) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

La cosa es que cuando deseo eliminar un usuario quiero que se eliminen sus perfiles y tambien se eliminen los perfiles de LPerfiles pero esto no esta pasando. Antes no me eliminaba los perfiles cuando eliminaba cierto usuario pero eso ya lo he conseguido y ahora falta que elimine en LPerfiles.

La verdad no se si estoy usando mal la clausula on delete cascade pero segun lo que estuve leyendo va detras de las foreign key asi que no se que me puede estar fallando.

Desde ya un saludo y gracias de antemano,

Comment: Cual es el error que tira o que error te da?

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema, vea [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9d50bda26e2878fd5ee75107c956adb).